# Distinct() on anonymous object not working in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I have read that the `IEqualityComparer` is automatically implemented on anonymous objects.

Below quoted from [here](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2008/03/25/and-equality-for-all-anonymous-types.aspx)

"Turns out the C# compiler overrides Equals and GetHashCode for anonymous types. The implementation of the two overridden methods uses all the public properties on the type to compute an object's hash code and test for equality. If two objects of the same anonymous type have all the same values for their properties – the objects are equal. This is a safe strategy since anonymously typed objects are essentially immutable (all the properties are read-only). Fiddling with the hash code of a mutable type gets a bit dicey."

After reading this, I am still receiving duplicates in my collection. Below is my LINQ query:

```
var calculations = (from dl in devianceLink.AsEnumerable()
                            join rec in receipts on new { TId = dl.PrimaryTransferId, EId = dl.EquipmentId } equals new { TId = rec.TransferId, EId = rec.EquipmentId } into recTemp
                            from rec in recTemp.DefaultIfEmpty().AsEnumerable()
                            join iss in issues on new { TId = dl.SecondaryTransferId, EId = dl.EquipmentId } equals new { TId = iss.TransferId, EId = iss.EquipmentId } into issTemp
                            from iss in issTemp.DefaultIfEmpty().AsEnumerable()
                            let partitionedByTransferLinkIdRec = devianceLink.Join(receipts, dl1 => dl1.PrimaryTransferId, rec1 => rec1.TransferId, (dl1, rec1) => new { DevianceLink = dl1, Receipts = rec1 }).Where(r => r.DevianceLink.TransferLinkId == dl.TransferLinkId).ToList()
                            let partitionedByTransferLinkIdIss = devianceLink.Join(issues, dl1 => dl1.SecondaryTransferId, iss1 => iss1.TransferId, (dl1, iss1) => new { DevianceLink = dl1, Issues = iss1 }).Where(r => r.DevianceLink.TransferLinkId == dl.TransferLinkId).ToList()
                            where   
                                iss.EquipmentId != 0 && rec.EquipmentId != 0
                            select new 
                            {
                                TransferLinkId = dl.TransferLinkId,
                                ReceiptTransferId = dl.PrimaryTransferId,
                                IssueTransferId = dl.SecondaryTransferId,
                                ReceiptReversed = partitionedByTransferLinkIdRec.Any(r => r.Receipts.HasReversal.Value),
                                ReceiptReversedPartial = partitionedByTransferLinkIdRec.Sum(r => r.Receipts.QuantityOri) - partitionedByTransferLinkIdRec.Sum(r => r.Receipts.QuantityRev) == 0 ? false : true,
                                ReceiptCorrection = partitionedByTransferLinkIdRec.Any(r => r.Receipts.HasCorrection.Value),
                                IssueReversed = partitionedByTransferLinkIdIss.Any(r => (bool)r.Issues.HasReversal),
                                IssueReversedPartial = partitionedByTransferLinkIdIss.Sum(r => r.Issues.QuantityOri) - partitionedByTransferLinkIdIss.Sum(r => r.Issues.QuantityRev) == 0 ? false : true,
                                IssueCorrection = partitionedByTransferLinkIdIss.Any(r => r.Issues.HasCorrection),
                                DuplicateReceipt = dl.DuplicateReceipt,
                                HasVariance = rec.Quantity - iss.Quantity == 0 ? false : true,
                                EquipmentId = dl.EquipmentId,
                                ReceiptCheckSum = 0,
                                ReceiptQuantityOri = rec != null ? rec.QuantityOri : 0,
                                ReceiptQuantityRev = rec != null ? rec.QuantityRev : 0,
                                ReceiptQuantityCor = rec != null ? rec.QuantityCor : 0,
                                ReceiptQuantity = rec != null ? rec.Quantity : 0,
                                IssueCheckSum = 0,
                                IssueQuantityOri = iss != null ? iss.QuantityOri.HasValue ? iss.QuantityOri : 0 : 0,
                                IssueQuantityRev = iss != null ? iss.QuantityRev.HasValue ? iss.QuantityRev : 0 : 0,
                                IssueQuantityCor = iss != null ? iss.QuantityCor.HasValue ? iss.QuantityCor : 0 : 0,
                                IssueQuantity = iss != null ? iss.Quantity.HasValue ? iss.Quantity.Value : 0 : 0,
                                Variance = (rec != null ? rec.Quantity : 0) - (iss != null ? iss.Quantity ?? 0 : 0),
                                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                                UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now
                            }).ToList().Distinct();
```

The first two rows of the `calculations` results is as follow:

```
{ TransferLinkId = 1868649, ReceiptTransferId = , IssueTransferId = 44402996, ReceiptReversed = False, ReceiptReversedPartial = False, ReceiptCorrection = False, IssueReversed = False, IssueReversedPartial = True, IssueCorrection = False, DuplicateReceipt = False, HasVariance = True, EquipmentId = 8, ReceiptCheckSum = 0, ReceiptQuantityOri = 0, ReceiptQuantityRev = 0, ReceiptQuantityCor = 0, ReceiptQuantity = 0, IssueCheckSum = 0, IssueQuantityOri = 1, IssueQuantityRev = 0, IssueQuantityCor = 0, IssueQuantity = 1, Variance = -1, CreatedDate = 2021/08/14 21:43:25, UpdatedDate = 2021/08/14 21:43:25 }
{ TransferLinkId = 1868649, ReceiptTransferId = , IssueTransferId = 44402996, ReceiptReversed = False, ReceiptReversedPartial = False, ReceiptCorrection = False, IssueReversed = False, IssueReversedPartial = True, IssueCorrection = False, DuplicateReceipt = False, HasVariance = True, EquipmentId = 8, ReceiptCheckSum = 0, ReceiptQuantityOri = 0, ReceiptQuantityRev = 0, ReceiptQuantityCor = 0, ReceiptQuantity = 0, IssueCheckSum = 0, IssueQuantityOri = 1, IssueQuantityRev = 0, IssueQuantityCor = 0, IssueQuantity = 1, Variance = -1, CreatedDate = 2021/08/14 21:43:25, UpdatedDate = 2021/08/14 21:43:25 }
```

The `.Distinct()` call does not filter these out.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It may be easier to read, if instead of all ternary null checks, especially nested ones, you used a null-conditional and null-coalescing operators eg. `iss?.QuantityOri ?? 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `DateTime.Now` for Created/Updated, so it would be quite unlikely that values between entries would be the same, they most likely differ by fraction of millisecond. If you displayed the values with greater precision, eg. `.Ticks`, they would be different.

I think you should save `DateTime.Now` to variable before LINQ and use it, to ensure they are the same for all entries. Other option is to add it to the object after `.Distinct()`.

Comment: Let me give it a try. Good catch

Comment: @monstertjie_za: And probably use `DateTime.UtcNow`... timestamps should almost always be independent of the time zone of the computer on which they're recorded.